# Why can't I switch back to the desktop after using a TTY?

Tags: command-line, tty

I have pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and then I have pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>, but it doesn't come back to the graphical interface. What should I do?

Comment: If rebooting is an option, run `sudo reboot now`.

Comment: "sudo restart lightdm" should do it

Comment: Does ALT + --> arrow button bring you back (press it a few times).

Comment: Have you tried Alt-F2…F6?

Comment: Sometimes it's f3 and sometimes it's f8. If all else fails, restart lights.